# Adding the class from a span to li using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I add the same class of the span to the li element with dynamically with jquery
`<li class="efficiency"><span class="green">44.525</span></li>`

so I can end up with

`<li class="efficiency green"><span class="green">44.525</span></li>`

I try

```
$('.green').parent().css('background', 'red')
```

but won't work
thanks

Comment: $('li').addClass('green'); ??

Comment: this works...  http://jsfiddle.net/Kg32n/

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add the same class of the span to the li element with
>   dynamically with jquery

You need to use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('.green').parent().addClass('green');
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to ask / tell?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').parent().addClass('green');
// Or
$('.green').parent().addClass('green');
//Or
$('li').addClass('green');
//Or
$('li').parent().addClass($('span').attr('class').eq(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want

```
$('span').parent().addClass($('span').attr('class'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add the class of each `span` that is a child of a `li` element to its parent.

The **easiest way** to do this would be:

```
$('li > span').each(function(){
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .addClass(
       $(this).attr('class')
    );
});
```

With this code the following html:

```
<li class="efficiency"><span class="green">44.525</span></li>
<li class="efficiency"><span class="red">44.525</span></li>
```

Will become:

```
<li class="efficiency green"><span class="green">44.525</span></li>
<li class="efficiency red"><span class="red">44.525</span></li>
```

You could **specify the selector** to:

```
// Select by the 'efficiency' class
$('li.efficiency > span')

// Or select by the 'green' class of the child 'span' element
$('li > span.green')
```